# Не находит функцию .json() в Angular5

Tags: angular2, angular5

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему вылетает ошибка[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте ваш код. После его именно появилась проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Angular 5 нет метода json, потому что там обновили HttpModule. Теперь он называется HttpClientModule. Там где resp.json, просто замените на resp и все. В новом angular все уже в json Формате возвращается